# Как в curl_setopt обработать не путь к файлу а файл из переменной

Tags: php, curl

Имеется код

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => new CURLfile($file_name)));
$json = curl_exec($curl);
```

Как вместо пути к картинке в $file_name использовать сгенерированую картинку $image?

Просто вставив переменную?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => $images));
```

Comment: Что значит "файл из переменной" ? вы хотите именно картинку (файл) вставить? Такое не бывает в природе ))

Comment: @Arsen, прошу прощения за корявость изъяснения, я хочу $images = imagecreatefrompng('i_pict.png');